# Soliton in non-degenerate polymer

Tags: semiconductor-physics, phonons, solitons, quasiparticles, polymers

I just started reading about the conduction mechanism in polymer. From what i read, polarons are used as method of charge transportation in non-degenerate polymer. While for degenerate polymer, both charged soliton and polaron will do the job.

As i go a bit deeper, polaron can be defined as:

1. A polaron can be thought of as a bound state of a charged soliton and a neutral soliton of which the midgap energy states hybridize to form bonding and antibonding levels.
2. A Quasiparticle that is created through the interaction of
   charged particles ( electron or holes ) with Phonon.

If i understand it correctly, the definition of the polaron contradicts with its existance in non-degenerate polymer as non-degenerate polymer doesnt have soliton due to its topological reason.

Also, as i am quite new to all these terms (polaron, bipolaron, soliton, charged soliton and phonon), i tend to get confuse and couldnt differentiate each of them precisely in layman terms as most of the literature are mostly explained in what could say too "academic" for a starter like me.

Would someone be able to help me clear my confusion? Any help, advice and guidance are really appreciated. Thanks in advance